# Удаленный доступ в Windows 7

Tags: windows

На двух компьютерах стоит *WINDOWS 7*.

Как можно соединить их через обычные модемы 56k?

Comment: модемы какие?

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов соединить два компьютера. Полагаю что соединение через модемы 56к значит соединение через интернет, а не через локальную сеть.

В Windows 7 есть встроенное средство соединения компьютеров. Называется **Удаленный помощник**. С его помощью формируете файл приглашения, отсылаете его на другой компьютер по email или переносите, например, на флешке. На другом компьютере запускаете этот файл. Тогда начнется сессия. Этот режим дает возможность видеть экран другого компьютер, а также дает возможность управлять другим компьютером. Но на все действия надо получать разрешения с другого компьютера.

Другой встроенный способ - **Удаленный рабочий стол**. Для этого надо, чтобы компьютеры были в локальной сети, или у компьютера, к которому подключаетесь, был белый IP (у вас его скорее всего нет).

Обойти это ограничение можно, связав компьютеры через интернет в локальную сеть. Например, программа Hamachi позволяет создавать виртуальную локальную сеть. Работу в локальной сети вы наверное можете себе представить.

Также есть класс программ для удаленного управления. Например, популярная TeamViewer. Другие можно посмотреть так. Они позволяют расшаривать свой рабочий стол, обмениваться файлами, управлять другим компьютером. В них есть текстовой мессенджер и возможность голосового общения.

По поводу скорости 56 Кбит/с. Этой скорости хватит, чтобы работать на минимальных настройках. При этом не будут работать стили отображения, визуальные эффекты, не будет показываться окно при перетаскивании.

Answer (score 1):

1. Удалённые столы работать будут вполне адекватно и на 56к, но немного медленно.
2. Кроме Hamachi, TeamViewer и встроенных средств удаленного управления есть ещё замечательная программа Radmin. Преимущества её в обособленной работе (устанавливается как отдельная служба, довольно стабильно работающая даже при некоторых сбоях самой системы), не требует обязательного подключения к Интернет.
3. Прямой звонок с компа на комп при помощи модемов вполне реален, но придется сделать некоторые настройки прав доступа чтобы удаленное управление (неважно какой программой) стало возможным, а также некоторые настройки сетевого соединения. Что именно настраивать и как именно зависит от используемой программы, типа соединения и естественно операционной системы. Скажите как именно хотите настроить (с выходом в инет или без него) и какую программу использовать будете - скажу как настроить

по просьбе Anvar: прочитать можно тут [Локальная сеть через dial-up](http://freeproger.ru/index.php/programmy/80-lokalnaya-set-cherez-dial-up)

Comment: Spasibo danila za otvet, takzhe vsem ostalnym uchastnikam za pomosh. Danila ya hotel by soedinit dva compa s pomoshyu modemov, no bez interneta, na pryamuyu. Podskazhi pozhaluysta kak mozhno eto sdelat. Spasibo

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего подключить оба эти компьютера к сети интернет через dial-up. Либо как вариант использовать прямой звонок через телефонную сеть с одного компьютера на другой.

Answer (score 0):

на 56к удаленные рабочие столы вряд ли будут адекватно работать.Не ужели на ПК с WIN7 нету ethernet карточек?